# "can't resolve symbol 'audio/*'" and can't resolve symbol 'application/ogg'" in manifest.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest

I am trying to develop a media player. To add my app in launcher list, I did this in manifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mediapalayer01">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activity.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>       
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <data android:type="audio/*" />
                <data android:type="application/ogg" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
           </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

but it constantly gives error "can't resolve symbol 'audio/*'" and "can't resolve symbol 'application/ogg'". I have tried cleaning and building and syncing the project, and also invalidating the cash and restarting android studio.

Comment: what do you mean by getting solution?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="file"/>
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/ogg"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/itunes"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/ogg"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/itunes"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter
        android:priority="-1">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="content" />
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/ogg"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg"/>
        <data android:mimeType="application/itunes"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

it worked by using below code as intent filter

```
 <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/ogg"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/x-ogg"/>
                <data android:mimeType="application/itunes"/>
            </intent-filter>
```